# Unable to connect from SpagoBI to Cosmos public server

Tags: hive, spagobi, fiware-cosmos

Seems like the hive jdbc client version does not match the version on the cosmos server.

Any idea which specific jar files I should use on SpagoBI to provide the appropriate JDBC connection to the hive2  server on Cosmos.

Thanks!

See stack trace below:

```
Nov 26, 2015 5:35:06 PM org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection openSession
SEVERE: Error opening session
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=ms})
    at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:156)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:143)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:583)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:192)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at it.eng.spagobi.tools.datasource.service.rest.TestConnection.testDataSource(TestConnection.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

it.eng.spagobi.tools.datasource.service.rest.TestConnection.testDataSource: Error testing datasources
java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:10000/ms: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=ms})
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:594)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:192)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at it.eng.spagobi.tools.datasource.service.rest.TestConnection.testDataSource(TestConnection.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=ms})
    at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:156)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:143)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:583)
    ... 39 more
```